# Merge Orchard Blog Into Existing Website

Tags: content-management-system, integration, orchardcms, blogs

I'm trying to determine the best way to "merge" my orchard blog into my existing website. Currently the blog accessed outside the site.

I threw together a quick view in my MVC site that just loads the blog into an iframe. Any other ideas?

The blog is tuned up with a great theme and tons of mods & styling that matches my main site design to a T.

On the home page of my site, I'm using the RSS feed to output a list of the last 3 blog posts. My idea is that the user will click on a blog post link and go directly the view that hosts the blog in the inline frame.

I guess the only variable that I haven't handled yet is how to load up the correct page in the blog based on the link that the user clicked on my main site home page.

I've read other posts on this subject and it seems like the solution that is always offered is to merge all the code from the main website into Orchard which seems insane...I have a very large auction based website, taking all that logic & content and putting into Orchard is not an option.

Hope all that makes sense, thanks for the input. I can't think it would be a huge issue to "seamless" integrate my blog with my MVC site.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard was never designed to be integrated into an existing application, so something like what you've done is what you have to do. The iframe however has a number of problems, such as its fixed size, and awkward navigation. It's better to integrate data than markup. It's now easy to build WebAPI controllers to expose Orchard data. You could consume that data in your application and render it there. That enables you to manipulate the data before rendering, which is of course easier than manipulating rendered HTML. For example, you can build your own link URLs so that clicking on a post's title goes to an action on your site that fetches the post contents rather than the Orchard post URL.

One final comment: It is a little weird that an auction website would need to integrate a blog in the middle of its own rendering. Shouldn't the blog be a separate section of the site?

Comment: I appreciate the input, I see what you mean about integrating the data vs the rendered html, raw data is a better choice. Started reading this article about rendering orchard cms content via OData. I don't have much experience with WebAPI & Odata, but now sounds like a good time to learn.

This article has some great info in it.
http://www.cloudconstruct.com/blog/exposing-your-orchard-cms-content-to-your-other-company-applications-and-websites-via-odata

https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.OData

Comment: The blog will stay a separate section of the website, it's just another feature of the site that includes auctions, affiliate products, video and now the blog.

I don't want users clicking to read the blog and completely leaving the site, the idea is to provide all that functionality - auctions, video, blog, etc within the context of the main site. Less clicks the better :)

Thanks for the help on this!

Comment: There's no reason why the user would have to notice that a different IIS application is running both parts of the site, if the navigation and theme are consistent. Unless I'm missing something of course.

Comment: The theme/design is consistent, it's just the nav won't be integrated if I keep the site in another application.

But for now I"m fine with having it own it's own sub domain and I'll work on it as I find time.

blog.preppergearauctions.com

Comment: Why couldn't the navigation be consistent?

Comment: I guess it could be if I rewrote the methods that populate the navbar based on user sessions. The methods could be turned in JsonResult that I could reference from the blog.